# SharePoint - 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: error, site-collection, iis

If I want to browse to my site address i get this message: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

this is what i see in event viewer:

The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/ for site 1. The necessary network binding may already be in use. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: There is no restore point, so what do i have to do now?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your IIS bindings are screwed.

Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard - it'll reconfigure the IIS web application for your to the SharePoint Web App configuration that it knows about.

Answer (score 0):

Check here in your file server location

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\webapplication

restore previous web.config file and iis reset then check...........

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding this to help people/for future searches:

For more modern versions of SharePoint, a "500 Internal Server Error" can also be due to the AMSI integration introduced in 2023.

The case can be that the new SPRequestFilterModule is missing from the applicationHost.config file. This does not give anything useful in ULS or the event log. The best way to determine this cause is [by temporarily enabling IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://blog.kenaro.com/2023/09/18/internal-server-error-on-sharepoint-server-2019-o-premises-after-update/).

For more detailed information, please see Stefan Gossner's blog:

[Trending Issue: Module “SPRequestFilterModule” could not be found after September/October 2023 CU](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/10/17/trending-issue-module-sprequestfiltermodule-could-not-be-found-after-september-october-2023-cu/)